# Massive WordPress botnet hack attack - how to fight back?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, firewall, plesk

Surely many of you have read about the [WordPress botnet hacking attempts](http://www.nbcnews.com/technology/technolog/wordpress-accounts-are-under-botnet-attack-1C9342312) taking place over the last several weeks. I have seen a massive spike tonight and wanted to voice this information.

What are some ways to tighten up WordPress and the server environment to address brute force hack attempts?

I know this is not the intended use of Stack Overflow, but I know many of you are webmasters running WordPress and I hope this will be helpful to you and your clients/projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using Parallels Plesk Firewall to block IP addresses associated with this attack.

`Server Management` > `Tools & Settings` > `Firewall`

Click `Edit Firewall Configuration`, then the icon for `Add Custom Rule`.

```
Match: Incoming traffic
Action: Deny
Ports: All (or at least 80, and 443 if SSL)
Sources: all IPs below.
```

I had previously been using `.htaccess` in the root directory to restrict access, like so:

```
<Files *>
order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from 1.2.3.4
deny from 5.6.7.8
</Files>
```

I have also installed the following WordPress plug-ins:

Limit Login Attempts: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/limit-login-attempts/

Google Two-Step Authenticator: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-authenticator/

In the past thirty minutes, I've seen brute force attempts at several of my WordPress installations from these IP addresses:

```
190.234.216.92 # 12:05 AM CDT
201.240.162.223
180.151.140.137
178.61.152.129
187.202.244.21
194.44.84.85
1.54.9.202
5.46.71.93
123.28.90.52
113.182.216.235
118.172.136.255
189.238.204.124
187.149.54.161
27.75.87.103
204.44.158.11
219.92.194.35
212.253.62.52
79.134.140.222
109.127.164.147
183.80.145.45
58.186.5.37
123.21.195.28
186.160.7.50
187.152.42.228
1.179.159.129
92.47.171.78
187.170.115.29
190.233.229.55
202.179.20.181
61.28.152.30
181.64.188.226
203.194.116.98
113.172.86.89
161.246.193.147
117.223.56.73
178.168.37.228
125.161.8.238
101.51.197.248
180.191.91.210
121.1.38.244
94.247.129.203
91.216.189.82
182.18.208.2
58.186.34.96
27.109.119.200
121.54.112.183
103.3.80.207
1.4.225.183
190.119.34.83
110.54.233.98

49.49.210.189 # 12:35 AM CDT
113.165.162.170
201.173.85.250
190.119.20.173
124.105.160.244
201.141.76.93
123.21.109.49
122.53.79.32
183.80.8.204
201.102.186.62
182.18.208.4
180.191.111.75

124.82.238.54 # 12:43 AM CDT
223.206.192.208
124.106.123.179
```

I know this is not the intended use of StackOverflow, but I know many of you are webmasters running WordPress and I hope this will be helpful to you in securing your clients/projects.